# How to passed in the same page for another query with Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I can't understand how to pass a value `$_POST['status']` select to the drop down menu, and passed to another query in the same page for valorize the table all with a loop.

The page is Order.php

This is the code for create the drop down menu

```
<form method="POST" action>
<?php $stato_ordine="SELECT distinct status FROM orders" ?>
<select id="stato_ordine" name="stato_ordine" >
  <?php if($result= $link->query($stato_ordine)): ?>
   <option value=""></option>
    <?php while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()): ?>

      <option value="<?php echo $row['status']?>">  <?php echo $row['status']?></option>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

    <?php $result->free(); ?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

```
<button type="button" name="search" id="search" class="btn btn-info">Cerca</button>

</form>
```

This the part of code that should be run when i click the value in the drop down menu.

```
            <?php if(isset($_POST['status'])): ?>
        <?php
            $ordini_effettuati= "SELECT c.contactFirstName, c.contactLastName, od.orderNumber, od.productName,
                                                            od.priceEach, p.quantityOrdered
                                                            FROM customers c
                                                            INNER JOIN orders o
                                                            ON c.customerNumber = o.customerNumber
                                                            INNER JOIN orderdetails od
                                                            ON o.orderNumber = od.orderNumber
                                                            INNER JOIN products p
                                                            ON od.productCode = p.productCode
                                                            WHERE o.status=?
                                                            ORDER BY orderDate DESC" ;
            $ordini_effettuati->bind_param('s', $_POST['status']);
            $ordini_effettuati->execute();
            $result = $ordini_effettuati->get_result();
        ?>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="table-responsive" id="employee_details" style="display:none">
               <table class="table">
                     <thead>
                    <tr>
                         <th scope="col">#</th>
                         <th scope="col">Nome</th>
                   <th scope="col">Cognome</th>
                   <th scope="col">Numero Ordine</th>
                   <th scope="col">Articolo</th>
                         <th scope="col">Prezzo Singolo</th>
                         <th scope="col">Quantita</th>
                    <tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    <?php while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th scope="row">1</th>
                        <td><span><?php echo $row['contactFirstName']; ?></span></td>
                        <td><span><?php echo $row['contactLastName']; ?></span></td>
                        <td><span><?php echo $row['orderNumber']; ?></span></td>
                        <td><span><?php echo $row['productName']; ?></span></td>
                        <td><span><?php echo $row['priceEach']; ?></span></td>
                        <td><span><?php echo $row['quantityOrdered']; ?></span></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endwhile; ?>
            <?php $result->free(); ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

Instead this is the part of Ajax. every time I click on the menu it should pass the value

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#search').click(function(){
     var name = $('#stato_ordine').val();
         console.log(name);
     $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: {status: name},
      success: function(response){
        console.log(name);
      }
     });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You should listen for changes not clicks on your select element. Try $('#search').change( ...  What is the problem? Does the request get sent? If so, what is the response?

Comment: Semicolon and colon are not the same character, and `=` is not a comparison operator.

Comment: Kopz, if I replace click with change doesn't work, indeed the console.log doesn't print anythings. Teemu I don't understand what you have write explain yourself better

Comment: okay but this is an exercise. Let's stay on the question. And then I don't understand the negative feedback

Comment: you're right, but first I would like to solve this problem, then I will read guides to fix the possible sql injection. If I am in trouble, I will open another post for this problem. Thx all

Comment: I have modified the code, for avoid the sql injection. can we go back to the original question now?